# Web Service to retrieve drug-drug interactions?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, asmx, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone please suggest a free open source web service that I can use for retrieving drug-drug interactions?

Comment: This is really more appropriate for StackExchange's software recommendation's site: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I did that but no luck as of now.  Do you have any suggestion for the web services available?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Sorry. If you haven't already, you could look at this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_healthcare_software), maybe something on it will be useful? =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one.  http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/NdfrtAPIs.html#  But the comments say they are going to remove that information from that soon.